# How to reconcile Philippians 2:5-8 with Numbers 23:19 and Hosea 11:9?

Tags: contradiction, numbers, christology, philippians, hosea

Philippians 2:5-8 is commonly interpreted by many as a description of the incarnation of Jesus:

> 5 Have this mind among yourselves, which is yours in **Christ Jesus**, 6 who, though he was in the **form of God**, did not count **equality with God** a thing to be grasped, 7 **but emptied himself**, by taking the **form of a servant**, **being born in the likeness of men**. 8 And being found in **human form**, he humbled himself by becoming obedient to the point of death, even death on a cross. [Philippians 2:5-8, ESV]

However, Numbers 23:19 and Hosea 11:9 appear to preclude this possibility:

> **God is not man**, that he should lie, **or a son of man**, that he should change his mind. Has he said, and will he not do it? Or has he spoken, and will he not fulfill it? [Numbers 23:19, ESV]

> I will not execute my burning anger; I will not again destroy Ephraim; **for I am God and not a man**, the Holy One in your midst, and I will not come in wrath. [Hosea 11:9, ESV]

How can we reconcile these passages?

Comment: Ask yourself : Who was the original audience of Philippians? - What was the traditional Greek assertion of powerful human leaders : Alexander the Great, Julius Caesar? (Sons of Zeus/Jupiter) - Would the demigod concept apply to any real Hebrew man?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important phrase, "I am God and not a man" in Num 23:19 and Hos 11:9 is absolutely correct in three senses:

1. God is not man at the time it was written in the OT - the incarnation had not yet occurred!
2. God does not suffer from the sinful tendencies in sinful man.  Therefore, God is incapable of lying, unlike sinful humans that apparently find it rather easy to tell lies.
3. As Phil 2:5-8 ably testifies, God became man - took on the form of humanity, for a while but was later exalted to the highest place in the universe.  **HOWEVER**, the humanity that Jesus took "was without sin" (Heb 4:15).

Jesus was a man in every sense of the word but was still different - Heb 7:26-28 -

> Such a high priest truly befits us—One who is **holy, innocent,
> undefiled**, set apart from sinners, and exalted above the heavens.
> Unlike the other high priests, He **does not need to offer daily
> sacrifices, first for His own sins** and then for the sins of the
> people; He sacrificed for sin once for all when He offered up Himself.
> For the law appoints as high priests men who are weak; but the oath,
> which came after the law, appointed **the Son, who has been made
> perfect forever**.

There is no conflict whatsoever between Num 23:19 and Hos 11:9 vs Phil 2:5-8 - BOTH are completely true.

Comment: One should also note during the incarnation there still was no conflict. God was not a man in the sense that the two natures mingled. The fact that Jesus IS still fully man and having the full being of God still is just a fact of the hypostatic union. I think your answer still addresses the fundamentals well.

Comment: Did God fully dwell in the human vessel of Jesus of Nazareth only for 1-year, or for 33-years?

Comment: @WnGatRC456 There is no Biblical basis that Christ Jesus has two natures.

Comment: @carsonfel The entire Council of Nicea disagree with you, As do I.

Comment: @NigelJ The Council of Nicæa is not a Biblical source.

Comment: @carsonfel I don't get why quoting  any council supersedes biblical instruction - esp. here on BH, Quite bizarre!

Comment: @user48152 There's nothing wrong with citing them. It's only wrong if they form your basis of faith. In that sense, they would supersede biblical instruction.

Comment: What about Malachi 3:6?

Comment: @Alex - what of the accounts where Jehovah "regrets" (changes His mind) that He has done something such as Gen 6:6, 7, 1 Sam 15:11, 35, Ex 32:14, etc.

Comment: Indeed, those are all questions that need to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Although my answer is probably not the answer you expected, there is another way to "reconcile" the writings of Paul with the prior Jewish revelation.

With all respect for Paul, his works and his wisdom, the only way to really reconcile his words with the scriptures is to acknowledge that the writings of Paul are not the Word of God as given to the Prophets.

The Christology of Paul is contradicting the teachings of the Torah and the Tenakh in general, saying that God is not human.

Paul is even contradicting Jesus who - according to the reports in the Synoptic Gospels - was aware of his importance to convey the Word of God but also aware of the difference between him and God.

The most evident citation is from Mark 10:18

> And as he was setting out on his journey, a man ran up and knelt
> before him, and asked him, "Good* Teacher, what must I do to inherit
> eternal life?" And Jesus said to him, "Why do you call me good*? No
> one is good* but God alone.

On this background, the most consequent access to "reconcile" Paul's writings with the OT and the Synoptic Gospels is not to see his writings as a prophetic writing but as writings of the most important theologist of early Christianity.

*Referring to [this article](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/55906/mark-1017-18-aramaic-word-for-%E1%BC%80%CE%B3%CE%B1%CE%B8%E1%BD%B8%CF%82), the original wording may not be "good" but rather "holy".

Comment: With that kind of reasoning regarding "Paul's words with the scriptures is to acknowledge that the writings of Paul are not the Word of God as given to the Prophets" why did you not start with the Apostle John at John 1:1-14? After all it was John who declared that Jesus Christ as the "Logos/Word" is identified as God before Paul showed up. In fact, the Apostle John at 1 John 1:1-4 clearly describes Jesus Christ as the "Word of Life," i.e a person that he and the other disciples have seen and handled with their hands. Are John's words "not the Word of God as given to the Prophets?"

Comment: John (whose Gospel probably dates later than the Epistles of Paul) has the concept of the Word of God being the same as God. This supports the view of Paul but it does not really solve the inherent conflict in the Bible on "Christology".

Comment: As a Muslim studying the Bible (thus often on this site, but a guest) I should abstain from it but I cannot hold back from saying that later prophecy supports this view https://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/4:171

Comment: Paul does not teach that Christ is God, but rather identifies the Father as God in v. 11, and identifies the Father as the "one God" in Eph. 4:6. Contradictions to this truth are not inconsistencies on the part of Paul, but rather on those who interpret his epistles.

Comment: @carsonfel I would be happy if you could explain your interpretation of this passage in an answer to the above question

Comment: @Dflat As flattering as that is, I do not believe that any human being has the right to give their own private interpretation of the Scripture (I Pet. 1:20). It is not up to human beings to decide what God means. That said, I have provided an answer using explanations from the Bible. It is, suffice to say, not a very popular answer, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 1):

With whom was Jesus equal?

| Phil. 2:5-6 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>5</sup>Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ Jesus, <sup>6</sup>who, being in the form of God, did not consider it robbery to be **equal with God**, |

With whom was Jesus equal? Paul said, "God."

Is Jesus equal in the sense that He is also God?

| Isa. 46:5, 9 CEV |
| --- |
| <sup>5</sup>Can anyone compare with me? **Is anyone my equal?** <sup>9</sup>**I *alone* am God!** There are no other gods; no one is like me. Think about what happened many years ago. |

Is Jesus equal in the sense that He is also God? God said, "I alone am God". Nobody can be equal to God in the sense that they are also God.

Is Jesus equal to God in terms of authority?

| I Cor. 11:3 GW |
| --- |
| <sup>3</sup>However, I want you to realize that Christ has authority over every man, a husband has authority over his wife, and **God has authority *over* Christ**. |

Is Jesus equal to God in terms of authority? Paul said, "God has authority *over* Christ". Paul did not mean that they were equal in terms of authority.

In what way then can our Lord Jesus be equal with God? In form.

What does it mean to be in the form of God?

| Phil. 2:5-6 Greek |
| --- |
| <sup>5</sup>τοῦτο γὰρ φρονείσθω ἐν ὑμῖν ὃ καὶ ἐν **Χριστῷ ᾿Ιησοῦ, <sup>6</sup>ὃς ἐν *μορφῇ* Θεοῦ** ὑπάρχων οὐχ ἁρπαγμὸν ἡγήσατο τὸ εἶναι ἴσα Θεῷ, |

| Chris. in the Making, p. 115 |
| --- |
| "... it has long been recognized that **μορφῇ (form) and *εἰκών (image)* are near synonyms** and that in Hebrew thought the visible ‘form of God’ is his glory." |

<sup>(Christology in the Making: An Inquiry Into the Origins of the Doctrine of the Incarnation, Dunn, James D. G. Grand Rapids, Michigan: Wm. B. Eerdmans Publishing Co., 1996)</sup>

What does it mean to be in the form of God? The Greek reads, "ἐν μορφῇ Θεοῦ." What was understood to be synonymous with the word "μορφῇ"? According to James Dunn, a New Testament scholar and theologian, "εἰκών (image)". What Paul wrote to the Philippians is the equivalent of what he wrote to the Corinthians in II Cor. 4:4, in that Jesus is in the image of God.

What does it mean to be in God's image? Does God have a literal appearance? What is an attribute of God?

| I Tim. 1:17 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>17</sup>Now to the King eternal, immortal, **invisible**, to God who alone is wise, be honor and glory forever and ever. Amen. |

What is an attribute of God? Paul said, "invisible". Unlike Jesus, the true God cannot be seen and therefore does not have a literal form or image.

What does it mean then to be in the image of God?

| Eph. 4:24 CEB |
| --- |
| <sup>24</sup>and clothe **yourself** with the new person created **according to God’s image in justice and true *holiness***. |

What does it mean then to be in the image of God? Paul explained, "in justice and holiness." Who are also expected to be in God's image? Paul said, "clothe yourself with the new person created according to God's image". Who was Paul speaking to? The members of the Church of Christ. We are instructed to be like God in image or holiness, just as Christ already is. It is in this sense that the Scripture allows for Jesus to be equal with God.

Why is holiness the image of God?

| I Pet. 1:16 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>16</sup>because it is written, "**Be holy, for I am holy**." |

Why is holiness the image of God? God said, "for I am holy".

What was Christ found in appearance as?

| Phil. 2:8 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>8</sup>And being **found in appearance as a *man***, He humbled Himself and became obedient to the point of death, even the death of the cross. |

What was Christ found in appearance as? Paul said, "as a man."

Is this also figurative? Is Jesus man in appearance only? How did our Lord Jesus Christ introduce Himself?

| John 8:40 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>40</sup>But now you seek to kill Me, **a *Man* who has told you the truth which I heard from God**. Abraham did not do this. |

How did Christ introduce Himself? Jesus said, "Man". Hence, Jesus is man not only in appearance, but in nature. From whom did Jesus hear the truth? Jesus said, "I heard from God." The one who hears is different from the one who is heard.

What is Christ's nature according to the Apostles Peter and Paul, respectively?

| Acts 2:22 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>22</sup>"Men of Israel, hear these words: **Jesus of Nazareth, a *Man* attested by God** to you by miracles, wonders, and signs which God did through Him in your midst, as you yourselves also know— |

| I Tim. 2:5 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>5</sup>For there is one God and **one Mediator between God and men, the *Man* Christ Jesus**, |

What is Christ's nature according to the Apostles Peter and Paul, respectively? They say, "Man". Was Jesus a man attested as God? Peter said, "by God". The one who attests is different from the one being attested. To whom does Jesus mediate man? Paul said, "God". Jesus the Mediator is different from the God to whom He mediates.

What is Christ's nature according to the Prophets Isaiah and David, respectively?

| Isa. 53:3 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>3</sup>**He is despised and rejected by men, a *Man* of sorrows** and acquainted with grief. And we hid, as it were, our faces from Him; He was despised, and we did not esteem Him. |

| Ps. 80:17 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>17</sup>Let Your hand be upon **the *Man* of Your right hand, upon the Son of Man** whom You made strong for Yourself. |

What is Christ's nature according to the Prophets Isaiah and David, respectively? They say, "Man".

How should we recognize God?

| Hos. 11:9 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>9</sup>I will not execute the fierceness of My anger; I will not again destroy Ephraim. For **I am God, and *not man***, the Holy One in your midst; and I will not come with terror. |

How should we recognize God? God said, "I am God, and not man."

How should we recognize man?

| Ezek. 28:2 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>2</sup>"Son of man, say to the prince of Tyre, 'Thus says the Lord GOD: "Because your heart is lifted up, and you say, 'I am a god, I sit in the seat of gods, in the midst of the seas,' yet **you are a man, and *not a god***, though you set your heart as the heart of a god |

How should we recognize man? God said to the prince of Tyre, "you are a man, and not a god". God is God, and man is man. God is not man, and man is not God. Jesus, who is man, therefore, cannot be God.

---

The teaching that Jesus is both man and God arose during the [apostasy](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/59438/40940), and was developed in [response](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/56425/40940) to external pressures from the pagans.

Comment: As I was reading your words I was anticipating these almost final words of yours. "In this way, Jesus was "equal" with God, not by being God, but by being equal in holiness, for He committed no sin, and it is to this standard that we must also strive." Why did the Jews accuse Jesus of blasphemy for claiming to be equal to God at John 5:18? Or claiming to exist before Abraham at John 8:58? John 10:30, "I and the Father We are one?" And the Son of God at John 19:7? Also, Jesus took the form/morphe of a man at Philippians 2:7-8. Does this mean Jesus is not a man in your thinking?

Comment: With regards to the Jews, Jesus states that they could not understand His speech (John 8:43). As for Christ being man, He states definitively that He is man (John 8:40). Also, the word used to described Jesus' "appearance" as a man is "schema" not "morphe".

Comment: The Jews knew what Jesus was teaching. Jesus pointed out the dullness of their understanding and their misinterpretation of His words. They were blind and did not realize their condition. That's the point of John 8:43. And the word "morphe" is used at Philippians 2:6, "always existing as God and at vs7 taking the form/morphe of a man. Same word is used. What your doing is applying "schema" at vs8 after the fact of Him taking the form of a man. Read the trial record at Matthew 26:57-66. Note vs63 where Jesus is asked to swear as to His identity. Are you the Christ/the Son of God?

Comment: v. 7 says he is in the "form of a bondservant." Also, you are wrongly equating being a "son of God" to being God in nature, for if that were the case, then those who believe in Christ would also qualify to be God. (John 1:12)

Comment: Taking the form of a bondservant is taking the form of a man. Hence your word "schema" at vs8, "And being found in appearance as a man." Why did the Jews accuse Jesus of blasphemy for claiming to be the Son of God since the Jews themselves claim to be sons of God? Jesus is the one and only Son of God at John 3:16 which means there are no others. Plus, it's a universal law that a son shares the same nature as its father. Jesus has two natures, one on His Father's side, deity. And one on His mother's side, human being. Jesus referred to Himself as the Son of God and as the Son of Man.

Comment: It does not say that being a bondservant means being a human, that's your own conclusion. If this "universal law" upon which you base your faith is applicable in this case, then that would mean that Adam is fully God, for he had no human parents, only God. Jesus is indeed the only Son of God, and a person is one with Him (Eph. 2:15) by being in His body (Rom 12:4-5) or Church (Col. 1:18), and as such are considered joint heirs with Him (Rom. 8:17).

Comment: "it has long been recognized that morphe (form) and eikon (image) are near synonyms and that in Hebrew thought the visible ‘form of God’ is his glory." I would suggest if you believe a writer used words with similar meaning but did not intend the reader to understand there was some difference intended, you will not understand the truth of the passage.

Comment: @RevelationLad Sometimes synonyms are just synonyms, take Isa. 1:18 for example, which uses no less than 3 different words to describe the color red.

Comment: @RevelationLad I never stated that these words were without different nuances, but this is irrelevant with regards to doctrine. They are as you say, "embellishments". Decorative. One person may say that an object is red, another may say it's scarlet, another may say it's crimson, but they're all referring to the same object and are all describing the same thing. Neither expression is more right or more wrong than the other. They are all correct. They are all understood to be the truth. I would leave a suggestion for you: don't fall prey to what's written in II Tim. 2:14 (NIV).

Comment: @RevelationLad As you keep using the strawman argument, I'd like to state that I never mentioned the color white, but since you bring it up, your conclusion that one type of forgiveness will last and the other won't is already going beyond what is written, which is in violation of I Cor. 4:6, which is why such disputes arise and is exactly how the truth becomes perverted.

Comment: @carsonfel Your hint on Eph. 4:24 where Paul extends the attribute image on normal Christians is very helpful. I consider to review the passages that according to their wording infringe the Unity of One God under this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! This is probably the shortest answer I've ever given. The point of Numbers 23:19 is to show that God is not like man who lies and does not keep his word.

God does not change, nor does God need to repent. Romans 3:4, "May it never be! Rather, let God be found true, though every man be found a liar."

The point of Hosea 11:9 is explained nicely by Barns notes. "Man punishes, to destroy; God smites to amend. God is not swayed by human passions."

Lastly, Numbers 23:19 does not preclude God from becoming a man just as Philippians 2:5-8 teaches.

Comment: If God becomes a man - He has changed!

Comment: @user48152 Good question? So what verse did you have in mind? There's about 10 or 12 verses that would apply.

Comment: Even if we assume that Jesus is God using Phillipians 2:6, if he emptied himself,  will he still be God if he emptied himself?  Where is it written in the Bible that the only true God emptied himself and still is the true God? If Philippians 2:7 really is speaking of making Christ’s divine nature “kenoo,” then it has been made void, hollow, useless, false, null, and of no effect. That means that  Jesus was void of a God nature and was only human.[

Answer (score 0):

> God is not man, that he should lie,
> or a son of man, that he should change his mind.
> Has he said, and will he not do it?
> Or has he spoken, and will he not fulfill it?
> (Numbers 23:19 ESV)
> לא איש אל ויכזב ובן־אדם ויתנחם ההוא אמר ולא יעשה ודבר ולא יקימנה

> I will not execute my burning anger;
> I will not again destroy Ephraim;
> for I am God and not a man,
> the Holy One in your midst,
> and I will not come in wrath. (Hosea 11:9)
> לא אעשה חרון אפי לא אשוב לשחת אפרים כי אל אנכי ולא־איש בקרבך קדוש ולא אבוא בעיר

Both passages contains statements expressing a common message:

- God, לא, singular (not אלהים, plural) is not a man, איש that He should lie, or a son of אדם, that is Adam that He should change His mind.
- I am God, לא, singular (not אלהים, plural) not a man, איש

In both cases "God" is described, or describes Himself using [לא](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H410&t=KJV) which is always singular, not אלהים, which is plural but usually understood as singular. In other words, both passages describe God in language which is unmistakably singular in nature. Both repeat the statement that God is not a man, [איש](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H376&t=KJV). In Numbers, there is an added statement, *God is not a son of man*. However, the text clearly distinguishes the two types of man, איש and אדם and more specifically we read, God is not a son of Adam.

Obviously, God is not a son of man **or** a son of Adam, but the failure to correctly convey the original text obscures the literal message: God (לא) is not a son of **Adam**. When He comes to earth as the Holy One in our midst, it was not in wrath, but in humble humility:

> <sup>6</sup> who, though he was in the form of God, did not count equality with God a thing to be grasped, <sup>7</sup> but emptied himself, by taking the form of a servant, being born in the likeness of men. <sup>8</sup> And being found in human form, he humbled himself by becoming obedient to the point of death, even death on a cross. (Philippians 2)