# Could (αγαθος) in Matthew 19:17 be explained with (δικαιον) in 1 John 2:1?

Tags: matthew, 1-john

Matthew 19:17; Greek New Testament;

> 17 ο δε ειπεν αυτω τι με λεγεις αγαθον ουδεις **αγαθος** ει μη εις ο θεος ει δε θελεις εισελθειν εις την ζωην τηρησον τας εντολας

Matthew 19:17; KJV;

> 17 And he said unto him, Why callest thou me good? there is none **good** but one, that is, God: but if thou wilt enter into life, keep the commandments.

1 John 2:1; Greek New Testament;

> 2 τεκνια μου ταυτα γραφω υμιν ινα μη αμαρτητε και εαν τις αμαρτη παρακλητον εχομεν προς τον πατερα ιησουν χριστον **δικαιον**

1 John 2:1; KJV;

> 2 My little children, these things write I unto you, that ye sin not. And if any man sin, we have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the **righteous:**

1 John 2:1; DRB;

> 2 My little children, these things I write to you, that you may not sin. But if any man sin, we have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the **just:**

Could **αγαθος** in Matthew 19:17 be explained with **δικαιον** in 1 John 2:1?

Comment: I am not sure I even understand your question.  Good and righteous are separate qualities which are related but still quite distinct.

Comment: @Dottard you fully understood my question: are good=righteous?

Comment: As any lexicon will show, "good" does not equate to "righteousness".  "Good" can apply to food or clothing but such can never be described as "righteous".  They are quite distinct.

Comment: @Dottard could you, please write your views in an answer post?

Comment: I have also been wondering about the word good. See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/55906/mark-1017-18-aramaic-word-for-%e1%bc%80%ce%b3%ce%b1%ce%b8%e1%bd%b8%cf%82

Answer (score 2):

Good (αγαθος) and righteous (δίκαιος) are quite separate qualities.  For example, we have a number of things that are good but not righteous.  In the eyes of some, those that are righteous are not necessarily good but often despised.

To be more specific, the following are described as "good" but are not righteous and cannot be:

- Matt 7:11 - good gifts
- Matt 7:17 - good tree
- Matt 12:35 - good treasure

Similarly, being righteous requires much more than being good.  I might do a good deed for my neighbor but that does not make me righteous.

It must be admitted, that occasionally, "good" is used a very loose synonym for something that might be construed as "righteous" such as Matt 22:10, 5:45, but this is a stretch.

The fundamental problem here is the meaning of αγαθος (good) is merely something that meets a high standard or something that deserves merit (BDAG).  That a "good" thing is merely a useful thing.  That is very different from something that is righteous.

Comment: are two greek words in Matthew 19:17 and 1John 2:1 like the two Hebrew words: צדק and טוב?

Comment: @salah - that should be the subject of another question